# Do the new Nintendo 3DS and new Nintendo 3DS XL have swappable faceplates?

Tags: new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

Do the new Nintendo 3DS and new Nintendo 3DS XL have swappable faceplates? I saw that the new Nintendo 3DS has swappable face plates, apparently for the ambassador edition, and was wondering if the same applies to the new Nintendo 3DS XL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the New Nintendo 3DS has swappable faceplates. The New Nintendo 3DS XL does **NOT** have that option.

Sources:

- [Destructoid](http://www.destructoid.com/uh-nintendo-there-are-now-54-new-3ds-face-plates-282652.phtml):

  > It's a common sentiment, I'm sure, but I'll say it anyway: too bad the New 3DS XL doesn't support swappable face plates. As much as I like the designs, if and when I upgrade, I want the big screen.
- [Crave online](http://www.craveonline.com/gaming/articles/810661-nintendos-new-3ds-consumers-mind):

  > The problem is that North America will only get one New 3DS option, and it’s the New 3DS XL. The New 3DS XL doesn’t support faceplate swapping, so consumers will be stuck with only two color options at launch, neither of which stand out nearly as much as their New 3DS counterparts.